# Why do i get "Unresolved reference: bind" error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I keep getting the error "Unresolved reference: bind" that bind is not resolved althought i added it in the gradle files.

App gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
  ...
  ...
  dataBinding {
    enabled = true
  }
}


dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  //kotlin
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
  //support
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.3"
}

kapt {
  generateStubs = true
}
```

Example of code i get error on:

```
private val currentStatusTextView: TextView by bind(R.id.text_current_status)
```

How can i fix this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android-kotlin error : unresolved reference databinding & ActivityMainBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521478/android-kotlin-error-unresolved-reference-databinding-activitymainbinding)