# android:kotlin how to solve databinding error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Im using kotlin with android vision api for face detection.The build fails when I try to run the project.It looks like this[image]

It gives **kotlin compilation errors**.I suppose there must be some version conflicts with respect to kotlin databinding , gradle etc.I tried various answers in the stackoverflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521478/android-kotlin-error-unresolved-reference-databinding-activitymainbinding)  but can't find the solution.

**This is my build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.ex1"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner         "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10"

implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

**This is my build.gradle(root)**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
ext.gradle_version = '3.2.0-alpha10'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.10"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
}

task delete(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any help will be really useful.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

please check this

```
    ext.gradle_version = '3.2.0-alpha10'
```

And

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

Also

```
   kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10"
```

gradle version not the same

Comment: When I tried giving the same gradle version(3.2.0-alpha10), it asks me to update the gradle to 3.3.1.When I updated it to 3.3.1,it errors: unresolved:com.android.databinding:compiler:3.3.1

Comment: It didnt work.I tried gradle version as 3.1.0-beta1 but  it errors:Data Binding annotation processor version needs to match the Android Gradle Plugin version. You can remove the kapt dependency com.android.databinding:compiler: 3.2.0-alpha10 and Android Gradle Plugin will inject the right version.But If I remove,again, it asks to update gradle avoiding which again errors!!